# SQL update query using aggregate function and group by in where clause?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that holds listing information for housing properties. A property may be in the table multiple times, once for every time it was listed. Here are the relevant columns:

```
ListingID <- primary key
PropertyID
ListingEndDateTime
```

I am trying to develop a query to update the EndDateTime for the **most recent** listing for every property in the table. The query will set the EndDateTime to the same value for every property.

I've tried a few approaches have been so far unsuccessful. How do I write such a query?

Comment: Thanks to everyone who posted. I didn't realize that I should have been doing the complex stuff as part of the update clause instead of trying to do it in the where clause.

Comment: feel free to upvote any answers you found helpful ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the following assumes ListingID is an auto_incrementing primary key:

```
update PropertyListing p
inner join
(
select
 max(ListingID) as ListingID,
 PropertyID
from
 PropertyListing
group by
 PropertyID
) latest on latest.ListingID = p.ListingID
set
 p.ListingEndDateTime = now();
```

Comment: I built on this concept and added a Max(EndDateTime), which eliminated the requirement of it being an auto_incrementing key.

Answer (score 0):

This allows multiple listings for the same property per date, the latest ListingID in such cases will be used.  Otherwise, the latest date alone will identify the listing.

```
# create table PropertyListing(ListingEndDateTime Int, PropertyID Int, ListingID Int);

update PropertyListing L
inner join
(
select Max(B.ListingID) MaxListingID
FROM
(
select PropertyID, MAX(ListingEndDateTime) MaxListingEndDateTime
from PropertyListing
group by PropertyID
) A
inner join PropertyListing B
    on B.ListingEndDateTime = A.MaxListingEndDateTime and A.PropertyID = B.PropertyID
group by B.PropertyID, B.ListingEndDateTime
) C on C.MaxListingID = L.ListingID
set L.ListingEndDateTime = CURDATE() + 7;
```

I have used `CURDATE() + 7` arbitrarily, set it to whatever date you need for all the records.

Answer (score 0):

Might need tweaking, but you get the general idea (SQL Server 2005 onwards):

```
WITH cteMostRecent (PropertyID, ListingEndDateTime, rownum) AS
(
   SELECT PropertyID, ListingEndDateTime,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PropertyID ORDER BY ListingEndDateTime DESC) as rownum
   FROM MyListingTable
)  

UPDATE cteMostRecent 
SET ListingEndDateTime = someDate
WHERE rownum = 1
```